# How to pin and unpin Kendo UI Mobile drawer

Tags: user-interface, mobile, kendo-ui, drawer

Is there any way to pin/unpin the kendo mobile ui drawer? I dont think this is supported as of the moment.

Anyone can point me to right direction on how to achieve this?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?